# cloning TFVC repo in azure devops using code

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

is there a way to clone/download a TFVC repo from azure devops using code?
and migrate to git is not an option the repo should stay in TFVC format.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an [extension for Azure Repos that supported TFVC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team). But it's been deprecated since. The [repo is still there](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode), so you may be able to build a local copy. Or [grab the latest (quite old) version](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/releases/tag/v1.161.1).

Your closest alternative is to use the [Windows Explorer extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention) or [Team Explorer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#visual-studio-team-explorer-2019). Or using `tf vc` on the commandline, like many hard-core git users only using `git` from the cli.